# Spotify app closes randomly

Tags: motorola-moto-g, spotify

I have a Moto G that is running Android 4.4.4.

While using the Spotify app to listen to music, it suddenly closes without any error message. It simply vanishes and has to be restarted.

It looks like I am running out of memory, as it tends to happen when I am using other apps while Spotify plays in the background.

What can be causing this problem?

Comment: Is it the stock ROM? I'd normally never suggest a RAM manager, but apparently some of them can be used in the opposite way than normal: keeping an app alive. Do you have any auto tuners on, any schedulers or any RAM managers that may be killing the process? Have you reached out to Spotify about this?

Comment: @RossC it's the stock ROM, I have no RAM managers/schedulers/etc... installed. I will reach to them.

Comment: It's very odd, usually Android is OK at managing processes and a streaming music player is obviously very 'active' all the time. I'm at a bit of a loss as to why the device is doing this **unless** the app you load in front of it is very heavy, like a game. If a game is loaded it's possible you simply don't have enough RAM and the device prioritises the activities / services in the foreground killing others in the background. OR the app is using some media service required and is taking it away from Spotify.

Comment: @RossC I'm not playing games or using other heavy apps; usually it happens when I'm browsing the internet in Chrome with Spotify in the background: if I load a heavier tab, Spotify is closed.

Comment: Same problem. Happens with Spotify and also Soundcloud. Seems to be plenty of RAM free. Also using Chrome in foreground but often happens when just browsing, not necessarily loading a page.